# Finding the range of $f(x) = 1/((x-1)(x-2))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I want to find the range of the following function

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{(x-1)(x-2)} $$

Is there any way to find the range of the above function? I have found one idea. But that is too critical. Please help me in solving this problem .

Comment: DO you mean $\frac{1}{(x-1)(x-2)}$?

Comment: Remember, *to get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Comment: yes Alex . I want to mean the eqn what you have written .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

Let $$y=\frac1{(x-1)(x-2)}$$

$$\implies (y)x^2-(3y)x+2y-1=0$$ which is a Quadratic Equation in $x$

As $x$ is real, the discriminant must be $\ge 0$

$$\implies (3y)^2-4\cdot y\cdot(2y-1)\ge0$$

$$\implies y^2+4y\ge 0\iff y(y+4)\ge 0$$

Either $y\ge 0$ and $y+4\ge 0\implies y\ge -4\implies y\ge0$

or  $y\le 0$ and $y+4\le 0\implies y\le -4\implies y\le-4$

Comment: Thanks Lab . This answer is enough for me .

Comment: @OchenaPothik, my pleasure. Observe that, we can deal with $y=\frac{ax^2+bx+c}{Ax^2+Bx+C}$ in the same way, current one being a special case

Answer (score 2):

In addition to lab bhattacharjee's answer, I'd recommend you to think on the following (in this and other cases when you are after the range of the function)

1. For two values y is undefined, because you can't divide by 0
2. y is strictly less than 0 only for some small interval (which?), due to the definition of the denominator
3. For the same reason, for two open intervals(which?) y is strictly positive
4. You can conclude from these three statements that y never takes the value 0.

Comment: This advice is a valuable gift from you , Alex . Thank you too .

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

You are probably familiar with the curve $y=(x-1)(x-2)$. It is an upward opening parabola that crosses the $x$ axis at $x=1$ and $x=2$, and reaches a minimum value of $-\frac{1}{4}$ midway between $x=1$ and $x=2$.

Draw a picture of the parabola.

Note the function $y$, and therefore also $\frac{1}{y}$, is **symmetric** about $x=\frac{3}{2}$. So for the range of $\frac{1}{y}$ we need only look at $x\ge \frac{3}{2}$.

As $x$ travels over the interval $(2,\infty)$, the qantity $\frac{1}{y}$  goes from very large positive values towards $0$. That contributes the interval $(0,\infty)$ to the range.

As $x$ travels from $x=\frac{3}{2}$ towards $x=2$, the quantity $\frac{1}{y}$ travels from $-4$ towards $0$, through negative values. That conttributes the interval $[-4,0)$ to the range.

So the full range is $[-4,0)\cup (0,\infty)$.