# How to prove $\frac{a^2}{a-1} + \frac{b^2}{b+1} >= 1/3 $ when $a, b \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0}$ such that $a + b = 1$.

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, recreational-mathematics

Attempt:
\begin{align*}
\frac{a^2}{a-1}+\frac{b^2}{b+1} & = \frac{(a+b)(ab + a - b)}{(a-1)(b+1)}\\
& = \frac{ab + a - b}{(a-1)(b+1)} \\
& = \frac{ab+a-b}{(ab+a-b-1)} \\
& = \frac{a^2 - 3a +1}{a^2 - 3a + 2}
\end{align*}
Where do I go from here?
A solution without the use of calculus would be preferred, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems like you made a mistake in transcribing your work with the minus sign.

Comment: The title says $a+1$ but the body starts off $a-1$

Comment: Thanks for that, I've fixed it.

Comment: This inequality is not true. Take $a=\frac 34$ and $b=\frac 14$, and the left side comes to $-\frac{11}{5}$.

Comment: You changed the title to match the body; are you sure you shouldn't have changed the body to match the title ($a\color{red}+1$)?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426437/finding-the-range-of-fx-1-x-1x-2 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845952/range-of-the-function-fx-fracx214x9x22x3-where-x-in-mathbb

Answer (score 1):

$b=1-a$, so the expression is $\dfrac {a^2}{a+1} + \dfrac{(1-a)^2}{2-a}$.

Over a common denominator, this simplifies to $\dfrac{a^2-a+1}{(2-a)(a+1)}=\dfrac{\left(a-\frac12\right)^2+\frac34}{-\left(a-\frac12\right)^2+\frac94}$.

Since $0\lt a\lt 1$, the numerator and denominator are both positive.

The numerator is minimized when $a=\frac12$, and the denominator is maximized when $a=\frac12$.

Therefore, the fraction is minimized when $a=\frac12$, and it is then $\dfrac{\frac34}{\frac94}=\dfrac13$.

Comment: I answered the title of the question when it said $a+1$; it was subsequently changed to $a-1$