# Maxima and minima of $\frac{x^2-3x+4}{x^2+3x+4}$ without calculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus, maxima-minima, rational-functions

How to find the minimum and max values of $y=\frac{x^2-3x+4}{x^2+3x+4}$ for all real values of $x$ without using calculus?

Perhaps it could be done graphically by noting the fact that the numerator and denominator are a pair of parabolas symmetric about the $x$ axis, but I do not know how to continue.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is this question from?

Comment: An exercise book on quadratic equations

Comment: They did not specify that calculus mustn't be used, but I was curious if it could be solved in a simpler way

Comment: I have an idea without calculus using the discriminant. I'm going to post an answer soon.

Comment: Ratio of two quadratic expressions is a different curve from a parabola.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1414298/range-of-a-rational-function  and   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845952/range-of-the-function-fx-fracx214x9x22x3-where-x-in-mathbb  and  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426437/finding-the-range-of-fx-1-x-1x-2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the maximum of $f(x) = \frac{x^2-3x+4}{x^2+3x+4}$ be $m$. Then:

$$x^2-3x+4 = mx^2 + 3mx + 4m$$
$$(m-1)x^2 + (3m+3)x + (4m - 4) = 0$$

We want this equation to have only one real root (a double root), so:
$$\Delta = 0 \Rightarrow (3m+3)^2-4(m-1)(4m-4) = 0.$$

A similar process for the minimum ($n$) yields the same equation, as multiplying it by $-1$ does not change the values of $m$. Therefore, both the maximum and minimum values are given by this equation.

Comment: so this works for any function that can be expressed in the form of a quadratic equation right?

Comment: Yes, this does. This works in general for any rational function $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ where $f(x), g(x)$ are polynomials up to a quadratic.

Comment: thanks man, you saved me from a lot of differentiation and substitution

Comment: @Monocerotis No problem!

Answer (score 5):

$$\dfrac{x^2-3x+4}{x^2+3x+4}=1-\dfrac{6x}{x^2+3x+4}=1-\dfrac6{x+\dfrac4x+3}$$

Now if $x>0, x+\dfrac4x\ge2\sqrt{x\cdot\dfrac4x}=4$

$\implies\dfrac1{x+\dfrac4x+3}\le\dfrac17\implies-\dfrac6{x+\dfrac4x+3}\ge-\dfrac67$

If $x<0, x=-y, y>0, x+\dfrac4x=-\left(y+\dfrac4y\right)$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Hint wehave $$\frac{x^2-3x+4}{x^2+3x+4}=y$$
$$x^2(y-1)+x(3y+3)+4y-4=0$$ set the *discriminant greater or equal to zero*

Answer (score 0):

> They did not specify that calculus mustn't be used, but I was curious
> if it could be solved in a simpler way – Monocerotis Nov 20 at 8:19
>
> thanks man, you saved me from a lot of differentiation and
> substitution – Monocerotis Nov 20 at 8:46

The most simple way to solve your problem is by using calculus:

By applying the [quotient rule](https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-i-find-the-derivative-of-a-fraction), you get: $y'(x)=(\frac{x^2-3x+4}{x^2+3x+4})'=\frac{(2x-3)(x^2+3x+4)-(2x+3)(x^2-3x+4)}{(x^2+3x+4)^2}$.

After putting the condition $y'(x)=0$ and expanding the numerator of $y'(x)$, you obtain:

$x^2-4=0$, whose solutions are:

$x_1=2$ and $x_2=-2$.

In conclusion:

$y_{max}=7$ (for $x=-2$) and $y_{min}=\frac{1}{7}$ (for $x=2$).

Comment: OP  has specifically asked for solving this without Calculus