# find the range of following function : $f(x)=\frac {x^2 +x -2}{x^2 -x -2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am trying to find the range of following function: $f(x)=\frac {x^2 +x -2}{x^2 -x -2}$, when I try it, I sketch the graph and it was obvious that its range is $\Bbb R$, but I cannot find its range algebraically.

Note: I tried polynomial division and obtained $1 + \frac{2x}{x^2 -x -2}$, and I take derivatives to find critical points for global max or min but it did not work to obtain $\Bbb R$.

My question is how to find its range without using graphs?

Comment: Try using partial fractions with the denominator factoring as $(x-2)(x+1)$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845952/range-of-the-function-fx-fracx214x9x22x3-where-x-in-mathbb OR https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426437/finding-the-range-of-fx-1-x-1x-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

$$f(x)=\frac {x^2 +x -2}{x^2 -x -2}=t$$

$$\implies x^2(1-t)+x(t+1)+(2t-2)=0$$

$$\implies \Delta = (t+1)^2-4(1-t)(2t-2)≥0$$

So, you can solve last inequality by using elementary algebra.

Answer (score 3):

Since $f(1)=0$, $0$ belongs to the range. Since $\lim_{x\to2^-}f(x)=-\infty$, it follows from this and from the intermediate value thorem that the range contains $(-\infty,0]$. And, since $\lim_{x\to-1^+}f(x)=\infty$ and still because $f(1)=0$, the range contains $[0,\infty)$. Therefore, the range is $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

Function $f = \frac{x^2+x-2}{x^2-x-2}$ has horizontal asymptote $y= 1$ which is given by the quotient of the leading coefficients.

Moreover $x^2-x-2 = (x+1)(x-2)$ and so $f$ has poles (and thus vertical asymptotes) $x_1=-1$ and $x_2=2$.

Behavior at the borders:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty} = \lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty} = 1$ as above.

$\lim_{x\rightarrow-1^-} = -\infty$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow-1^+} = +\infty$ (the pole has multiplicity 1 and so there is a sign change).

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 2^-} = -\infty$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 2^+} = +\infty$ (the pole has multiplicity 1 and so there is a sign change).

The whole analysis shows that the domain is $\Bbb R\setminus\{-1,2\}$ and the range is $\Bbb R$ since $f(0)=1$ is attained (despite the fact that $y=1$ is an asymptote).

Comment: but your answer contradicts with answer key and previous answers answer is $R$

Comment: I've plotted the function with Maple.

Comment: $F(O)=1$ ?? Isnt it

Comment: Right. I'll change it.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing it as

\begin{gather*}
y=\frac{x^{2} +x-2}{x^{2} -x-2}\\
y\left( x^{2} -x-2\right) =x^{2} +x-2\\
( y-1) x^{2} -( y+1) x+( 2-2y) =0\\
\\
\\
\end{gather*}
As x belongs to R, the discriminant of the above equation must be greater than or equal to zero.
Find the discriminant, solve the inequality and you get the range of y.

Comment: In fact the discriminant is always positive, which is what it must be for the function to be onto $\;\Bbb R\;$ .

Comment: Thanks @DonAntonio, corrected it!

Comment: @IshraaqParvez Your answer is still incomplete. Because, discriminant can equal to $0$. So, "discriminant must be positive" is still not correct.